# JAXB unmarshalling returns object with null children

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal an xml file using jaxb. I generated the java classes by invoking xjc, that produced a lot of classes. The root class is document. It contains one attribute. When I unmarshal the xml file there is no exception thrown, but the attribute of class document is null. Why does the unmarshalling not fill the attribute?

My code in this respect is:

```
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(camtDocumentClass);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(camtFile);
```

The (shorted) xml document to unmarshal is:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04 camt.054.001.04.xsd">
    <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
...
    </BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
</Document>
```

The relevant generated classes are: Document

```
// Siehe <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Änderungen an dieser Datei gehen bei einer Neukompilierung des Quellschemas verloren. 
// Generiert: 2021.10.24 um 12:18:28 PM CEST 
//


package ch.eugster.camt05400104;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für Document complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="Document">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn" type="{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04}BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "Document", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Document", propOrder = {
    "bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn"
})
public class Document {
    
    public Document()
    {
        System.out.println();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn", required = true)
    protected BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 }
     *     
     */
    public BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 getBkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn() {
        return bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 }
     *     
     */
    public void setBkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn(BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 value) {
        this.bkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn = value;
    }

}
```

The attribute class is:

```
// Siehe <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Änderungen an dieser Datei gehen bei einer Neukompilierung des Quellschemas verloren. 
// Generiert: 2021.10.24 um 12:18:28 PM CEST 
//


package ch.eugster.camt05400104;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="GrpHdr" type="{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04}GroupHeader58"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Ntfctn" type="{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04}AccountNotification7" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *         &lt;element name="SplmtryData" type="{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04}SupplementaryData1" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04", propOrder = {
    "grpHdr",
    "ntfctn",
    "splmtryData"
})
public class BankToCustomerDebitCreditNotificationV04 {

    @XmlElement(name = "GrpHdr", required = true)
    protected GroupHeader58 grpHdr;
    @XmlElement(name = "Ntfctn", required = true)
    protected List<AccountNotification7> ntfctn;
    @XmlElement(name = "SplmtryData")
    protected List<SupplementaryData1> splmtryData;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der grpHdr-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link GroupHeader58 }
     *     
     */
    public GroupHeader58 getGrpHdr() {
        return grpHdr;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der grpHdr-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link GroupHeader58 }
     *     
     */
    public void setGrpHdr(GroupHeader58 value) {
        this.grpHdr = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ntfctn property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the ntfctn property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getNtfctn().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link AccountNotification7 }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<AccountNotification7> getNtfctn() {
        if (ntfctn == null) {
            ntfctn = new ArrayList<AccountNotification7>();
        }
        return this.ntfctn;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the splmtryData property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the splmtryData property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getSplmtryData().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link SupplementaryData1 }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<SupplementaryData1> getSplmtryData() {
        if (splmtryData == null) {
            splmtryData = new ArrayList<SupplementaryData1>();
        }
        return this.splmtryData;
    }

}
```

The xsd file is camt.054.001.04.xsd (it is too big to paste it here). You can find it at [here](https://github.com/genkgo/camt/blob/master/assets/camt.054.001.04.xsd)
As already said, the unmarshalling throws no exception. And I did not succeed debugging because I have not the relevant sources of the unmarshal classes. I examined the respective Question, but did not find the right solution.

Any idea? Thank you!
Christian